# iOS Augmented Reality Framework and some guidance

Tags: ios, frameworks, augmented-reality

I have done some iOS development before never quite something that handled the Camera (which is what I think I need to do) Could you point me in the right direction?

What I was requested to do is basically to have a QR code reader that can display certain information (images/video/text) and then take it further up a notch by adding augmented reality (not necessarily using said QR codes but within the same app).

I've looked for some Augmented reality frameworks for iOS and I found SimpleGeo https://github.com/simplegeo/SGAREnvironment but it's more of a location-based AR framework. Any others? Or should I not even include the QR reader and do everything with the AR framework?

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

- [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)
- [OpenCV iOS port](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/)
- [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) - Code bar generator (support for QR)
- [LibDecodeQR](https://github.com/josephholsten/libdecodeqr) (uses OpenCV)